# Drools Function unable to resolve method using strict-mode

Tags: java, tomcat, drools

I have a Drools file that I'm using for business logic on a Tomcat6 server running Java 1.7.0_131 inside a Docker container. When I run the code bellow:

```
package org.fosstrak.capturingapp
 
import org.fosstrak.capturingapp.util.Util; 
import org.fosstrak.ale.xsd.ale.epcglobal.ECReport;
import org.fosstrak.ale.xsd.ale.epcglobal.ECReports;
import org.fosstrak.ale.xsd.ale.epcglobal.ECReportGroupListMember;
import org.fosstrak.ale.xsd.epcglobal.EPC;
import org.fosstrak.capturingapp.util.SimpleEPCISDocument;
import org.fosstrak.epcis.model.ActionType;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import function org.fosstrak.capturingapp.util.Util.extractEPC;
import function org.fosstrak.capturingapp.util.Util.extractReportMembers;

// the global collector for all the EPCIS documents for further processing.
global java.util.List epcisResults

function List warehouseReportHandler(List reports, String reportName){
    // List of ECReports
    List epcs = new LinkedList();

    for(Object rs : reports){
        if(rs instanceof ECReports){
            ECReports rsc = (ECReports) rs;
            for(ECReport report : rsc.getReports().getReport()){
                if(report.getReportName() == reportName){
                    ecps.addAll(extractEPC(Util.selectTag, report));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return epcs;
}

rule "ADDITIONS Rule Tags from reader 'Reader_Warehouse_Shelve1' from the specName 'ECSpec'"
    dialect "java"
    when
        $reports : ECReports( reports != null)
        $epcs : LinkedList( size > 0 ) from collect (
            EPC() from warehouseReportHandler($reports, "additions")
            )  
    then
    
        SimpleEPCISDocument simpleDocument = new SimpleEPCISDocument();
        simpleDocument.addObjectEvent(
            $epcs, 
            ActionType.OBSERVE, 
            "urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:storing", 
            "urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:sellable_not_accessible",
            "urn:epc:id:sgln:76300544.00000.1",
            "urn:epc:id:sgln:76300544.00000.0"
            );
        
        System.out.println("\n=====================================================");
        System.out.println("Additions tags seen:");
        for (Object o : $epcs) System.out.println(((EPC)o).getValue());
        System.out.println("=====================================================\n");

        epcisResults.add(simpleDocument.getDocument());
end
```

I get the following error message:

```
21146 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.fosstrak.capturingapp.ECReportsHandler  - Unable to build expression for 'from' : Failed to compile: 1 compilation error(s): 
capture       |  - (1,45) unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.warehouseReportHandler(org.fosstrak.ale.xsd.ale.epcglobal.ECReports, java.lang.String) 'warehouseReportHandler($reports, "additions")' : [Rule name='ADDITIONS Rule Tags from reader 'Reader_Warehouse_Shelve1' from the specName 'ECSpec'']
capture       | Error importing : 'org.fosstrak.capturingapp.WarehouseReportHandler.warehouseReportHandler'[ warehouseReportHandler : Function Compilation error
capture       | warehouseReportHandler (line:28): ecps cannot be resolved
capture       |  ][ warehouseReportHandler : Function Compilation error
capture       | warehouseReportHandler (line:28): ecps cannot be resolved
capture       |  ]Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='ADDITIONS Rule Tags from reader 'Reader_Warehouse_Shelve1' from the specName 'ECSpec'']
capture       |     org/fosstrak/capturingapp/Rule_ADDITIONS_Rule_Tags_from_reader__Reader_Warehouse_Shelve1__from_the_specName__ECSpec__0.java (2:489) : The import org.fosstrak.capturingapp.WarehouseReportHandler cannot be resolved
```

I'm new to Drools. I am not sure if it's a syntax problem.

**Update:** I've removed the generics I had previously and tried to follow the examples given in the project, without success. (https://github.com/Fosstrak/fosstrak/tree/master/capturingapp/trunk/src/main/resources/drools)

Thank you everyone for your time

Comment: Looks like your drools might be using an older version of Java that doesn't allow parameterized types? What is line 17 as identified by the error message? Is it one of the function declarations?

Comment: Yes, the function declaration

Comment: What version of drools is this, and how have you configured its compiler?

Comment: Version 5.0.1 . I don't really know, I never used drools before and the code base is from an open source project ([Fosstrak capture application](https://github.com/Fosstrak/fosstrak/tree/master/capturingapp/trunk)) that I'm trying to use for my master thesis. They have a few drools examples in the main/resources/drools directory

Comment: Oof that's old. Ok so when I did drools 5.0 I found that I could never get it to work with parameterized classes. You can try changing it to just return List instead of List<Something>. Maybe someone else will show up and explain how to get it to work with parameters, but after 6-7 years I could never get it working.

Comment: That was my reaction during the whole thesis ahah

Comment: Your current version of the question is still using modern Java constructs. Use an indexed for-loop (eg. `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { ...`) If your Drools compiler is using Java 5 you really need to restrict yourself to the language features of that JDK.

Answer (score 0):

This line

`function List warehouseReportHandler(List reports, String reportName){`

defines the function with the parameter as a list. However the invocation

```
       $reports : ECReports( reports != null)
        $epcs : LinkedList( size > 0 ) from collect (
            EPC() from warehouseReportHandler($reports, "additions")
            )
```

shows a parameter of type ECReports is being sent in to the method. Can you fix this and try?